# как вытащить ошибки из subprocess python

Tags: python, subprocess

Суть следующая, имеется функция которая вызывает работу неких процессов. Настроено логирование (отдельная ф-ия) и все работает хорошо, но появилась необходимость при падении процесса выводить ошибку именно процесса , а выводится ошибка той функции которая его вызывает.

```
def run_process(cmd: list, log, **kwargs):
    .....
    logger.info('Running command "{}"'.format(' '.join(cmd)))

    kwargs.update(dict(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)

    with process.stdout:
        log_subprocess_output(process.stdout, log=log)
    process.wait()  
    if not process.returncode:
        logger.info('Completed successfully')
        return

    if process.returncode:
        raise Exception('Completed with errors \n {}'.format(?????))
```

?????? - что нужно подставить что б отловить ошибки процесса?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `try-catch` конструкцию.

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(...)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
```